# Frames are ignored when importing video into the video editor (Kdenlive, Shotcut)

Tags: kdenlive, shotcut, fps

I have a video downloaded from the Internet. The file properties indicate that the video has 29.75 fps.

[image: File props]

When I play this video frame by frame using the "E" key in the VLC player, it looks smooth and the frames are not duplicated. When I import this video into a video editor like KDENLIVE or SHOTCUT, it imports at 17.97fps.

[image: Kdenlive import]

Using "ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams video.mp4", I discovered that the video parameters r_frame_rate and avg_frame_rate are different.

codec_name=h264

codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10

profile=Baseline

codec_type=video

codec_tag_string=avc1

codec_tag=0x31637661

...

**r_frame_rate=119/4**

**avg_frame_rate=293000/16303**

time_base=1/90000

start_pts=0

start_time=0.000000

duration_ts=22009050

duration=244.545000

bit_rate=897235

max_bit_rate=N/A

bits_per_raw_sample=8

nb_frames=4395

nb_read_frames=N/A

nb_read_packets=N/A

extradata_size=25

r_frame_rate has a value of 119/4, which is equal to 29.75fps and avg_frame_rate has a value of 293000/16303, which is equal to 17.9721523646fps. Apparently video editors use avg_frame_rate when creating a project, but this leads to some frames being ignored during importing and playback. If I play a video frame by frame in a video editor, it duplicates the frames, as if the video really has 17.97 fps, and not 29.75 fps. Even if, when importing a video, I force 29.75 fps or change the fps after importing, Kdenlive and Shotcut still miss some frames. I tried using "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -q:v 1 img%d.png" to convert the video into a sequence of PNG images and got all the frames without gaps. Most likely, the problem of missing frames during import occurs due to differences in the r_frame_rate and avg_frame_rate parameters for the video. For some reason, the video editor does not take into account the value of the r_frame_rate parameter and ignores some frames, despite the fact that frames are present in the video. How to force a video editor to take into account all frames present in a video file? Is it possible to somehow change the avg_frame_rate, preferably without reencoding? Or should I use another way to import videos? Or am I missing something?